# PHP SQLite3. Защита бд паролем или шифрованием

Tags: php, sqlite, sqlite3

Расширение SQLite3 поддерживает защиту шифрованием бд, если это расширение собрано с такой поддержкой. Но я нигде не встретил рабочего примера такого шифрования, как собрать и тд. Видимо эта возможность особо не используется, собственно возникает вопрос, как тогда защитить БД SQLite от несанкционированного просмотра? Что в основном используется? Буду признателен за любой пример.

Comment: Если у тебя сервак mysql работает по локалу с твоим php то зачем тебе это? Если в него никто не попадет кроме тебя и хостеров)

Comment: Да ты что? почитай про SQLIte и подумай зачем мне это может быть нужно

Comment: Таким образом защитить данные не получится. При получении доступа к самому приложению будет доступ и к базе, так что смысла шифровать нет.

Comment: Согласен, но мне требуется защитить бд от не самых продвинутых пользователей

Answer (score 1):

Что вам мешает в базе хранить шифрованные значения и расшифровывать их на лету, ключ получать на лету из сети. Если приложение автономное, то смысла в хранении базы с "паролем" 0, так как ничего не мешает разобрать ваше приложение и найти пароль. С шифрованием базы, даже если локально сложность увеличивается, особенно если алгоритм кастомный. Плюс хорошо бы обфусцировать код.